# Texstudio - How to show custom toolbar

Tags: texstudio

To Texstudio users: I created a custom toolbar using Options, Configure Texstudio, Toolbar customization (please see screenshot). Unfortunately I don't see the new "Custom" toolbar in the menu (I have only the other ones like Math, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on toolbar (mine, for example, looks like this):

[image]

and you will see the menu:

[image]

There you could hide/show many toolbars.